# TypeError: ‘tuple’ object is not callable Solution - pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

I don't see were is the problem in the code.

**PROBLEM:**

Tried to run a python program and received error message:
`TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable Solution`

**Attempts to fix the Error**

- Looked through the syntax - didn't find any problems there.
- Didn't see any missing commas.
- Didn't see any incorrect Indexing Syntax.

[pastebin link](https://pastebin.pl/view/1f8242ec)

**Code**

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time
import random
import win32.lib.win32con as win32con

#Tile 1 position: X= 1018 Y= 159 RGB:(194, 78, 147)
#Tile 2 position: X= 1113 Y= 159 RGB:(3, 255, 255)
#Tile 3 position: X= 1196 Y= 159 RGB:(2, 247, 68)
#Tile 4 position: X= 1289 Y= 159 RGB:(247, 59, 59)

def KEYRIGHT(x,y):
  pyautogui.RIGHT
  time.sleep(0.01) 

def KEYLEFT(x,y):
  pyautogui.LEFT
  time.sleep(0.01) 
 

def KEYUP(x,y):
     pyautogui.keyUp
     time.sleep(0.01) 
def KEYDOWN(x,y):
  pyautogui.keyDown
  time.sleep(0.01)

while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:

    if pyautogui.pixel(1018, 159)(194, 78, 147):
     KEYRIGHT(1018, 159)

    if pyautogui.pixel(1113, 159)(3, 255, 255):
     KEYDOWN(1113, 159)

    if pyautogui.pixel(1196, 159)(2, 247, 68):
     KEYUP(1196, 159)

    if pyautogui.pixel(1289, 159)(247, 59, 59):
     KEYRIGHT(1289, 159)
```

Comment: The code you've posted would produce an indentation error.

Comment: If `pyautogui.pixel(1018, 159)` returns a tuple, `pyautogui.pixel(1018, 159)(194, 78, 147)` and similar lines are attempting to call that tuple as a function. What's your intent there, and what's the full error with traceback?

Comment: `(1018, 159)(194, 78, 147)`. Python thinks `(1018, 159)` is the function name and `(194, 78, 147)` are the arguments you are passing into that function. ```func(foo1,foo2)```. I think you might want `((1018, 159)(194, 78, 147))

Comment: What line throws the error? What are things like `pyautogui.pixel(1289, 159)(247, 59, 59)` supposed to mean? Are you trying to test if `pyautogui.pixel(1289, 159) == (247, 59, 59)` ? My guess is that those are the lines throwing the error.

Comment: @BuddyBob I don't think that you are correct in how the syntax works. Something like `f(1,2)(3,4,5)` is perfectly acceptable -- provided that `f(1,2)` is callable.

Comment: The error message is from `pyautogui` — so look there.

Comment: (1018, 159) is x and y, (194, 78, 147) are RGB values. The main idea was when the color of the pixel turns RGB colors to (194, 78, 147) it presses KEYRIGHT

Answer (score 1):

The `pixel` function apparently returns a tuple.
A tuple and the arguments to a function call both use parentheses.
So Python thinks you are trying to call a function with the args: `(194, 78, 147)` for red, green, and blue apparently.  But what you seem to want to do is check if the value returned by pixel is equal to the tuple `(194, 78, 147)`

Some objects are callable.  For example you could make a class that implements `def __call__(self, r, g, b)` and then make a function called `pixel` that returns this object that implements `__call__` and your code would run without syntax errors.

But the built in tuple type does not implement `__call__`, so "the 'tuple' object is not callable"

I think this is what you wanted:

```
if pyautogui.pixel(1018, 159) == (194, 78, 147):
 KEYRIGHT(1018, 159)

if pyautogui.pixel(1113, 159) == (3, 255, 255):
 KEYDOWN(1113, 159)

if pyautogui.pixel(1196, 159) == (2, 247, 68):
 KEYUP(1196, 159)

if pyautogui.pixel(1289, 159) == (247, 59, 59):
 KEYRIGHT(1289, 159)
```

Comment: Thank you  so much !

Comment: The OP said the error message was `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable Solution`, not `the 'tuple' object is not callable`.

Comment: @martineau I don't think "is not callable Solution" is a valid error. I did a quick search through the CPython source, and couldn't find any instances where `Solution` would be placed after the error. I think that's an error on the OP's part.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: I know and that's why I made the comment under the question that the error must be from `pyautogui` (given that it's not a standard CPython interpreter message). But it could have just been a misstatement, too.

Comment: @karolxxx if this solves your problem (and it probably does), consider marking it as "accepted" (using the check mark next to the answer).

Comment: FWIW, I think "Solution" means that it was likely copied from a homework assignment, and the solution part was what needed to be filled in by the student.  However, I'm happy to help students learning python if that is the case.